# Denotation of composite of relations

Tags: relations

We denote the composite of relation R and relation S by $S \circ R$.

Since the order matters, meaning composite of R and S is not composite of S and R. I am trying to understand why the denotation of composite of R and S puts S before R, which is unintuitive for me.

Can anyone help me understand this? Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's in order to maintain consistency with function composition and application. For functions $g=S, f=R$, the notation for composition of relations $S, R$ should be the same as that of composition of $g,f$: $(g\circ f)(x) = g(f(x))$.

If composition were defined so that the first function $f$ applied (or relation $R$) appears "leftmost", then we would want to (and have to) write function application *on the right* if we wanted the order to look the same in both composition and application. Otherwise, the orders are different: suppose $|$ denotes this 'reversed' composition, first $R$ then $S$: $R|S = \{(x,z)\mid \exists y (xRy, ySz)\}$. Then, somewhat unintuitively, $(R|S)(x) = S(R(x))$.

Note that historically, relation composition *has* also been defined as in the above paragraph, with that very symbol $|$, and function application *has* been (and in some subjects *is* currently) written on the right. These conventions are in use within particular areas of mathematics (group actions, for example; other areas of algebra; some presentations of category are a few that come to mind). Function application on the right looks better (*imho*) and is probably more common without parentheses, or with parentheses around both function and argument(s) rather than around just the argument(s): compare $x\sigma, x\sigma\tau$, or $(x\sigma), (x\sigma)\tau, (x\sigma\tau)$, and so on, with $(x)\sigma, ((x)\sigma)\tau$.

In mainstream presentations of, say, set theory, such as you'd find in a "Chapter 0", these forms are less (and less) common. Example: Quine's book *Set Theory and Its Logic* gets very worked up on the subject of the proper order for writing composition: he favors the $R|S$ order, referring to it as "my way, Schroeder's way" (Schroeder being the inventor of 'relational  algebra', and as of Schroeder-Bernstein Theorem fame).

Comment: I thought there were still many algebraists out there who write functions on the right. Using ";" for what you call "reversed" relational composition works out very nicely in many computer science contexts.

Comment: @RobArthan True. I replaced my last sentence with a few more which hopefully are more specific. Originally I was thinking more about what you're likely to find in a "Chapter 0", or examples such as Quine's, as cited in the answer.

Comment: @BrianO Your explanation is quite intelligible to me. I understand that relations are a generalizations of functions; and composite of functions is denoted that way; for consistency, composite of relation should be that way, too.

Comment: The theory of modules over a non-commutative ring is an obvious example where it is vital to be able to work with both conventions. if the non-commutative ring is a ring of matrices, then we are just talking about whether to represent vectors as row vectors or column vectors. If "mainstream presentations" are encouraging a bias towards functions on the left, then those presentations are encouraging a decrease in mathematical maturity: a competent mathematician should be able to work with either convention (or both).